# Twilio Gather, take user's input without delays

Tags: twilio

I am using gather verb to take user's input, but I play mp3 before user press a key.
The problem is I would like to post a user's input to action URL before mp3 file is finished to play.
My TwiML doesn't take any user's inputs until the mp3 file is finished to play.
I am not sure if there is a way to just post user's input right away when user press a key.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play>http://www.action.com/greeting.mp3?1925924752</Play>
    <Play>http://www.action.com/selection.mp3?1925924752</Play>
    <Gather NumDigits="1" Timeout="5" Method="GET" Action="Http://www.action.com/handler.Php?Repeated=1"/>
    <Redirect Method="GET">http://www.action.com/handler.php?repeated=1</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Just drop those [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) verbs into your [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Play>http://www.action.com/greeting.mp3?1925924752</Play>
  <Gather NumDigits="1" Timeout="5" Method="GET" Action="Http://www.action.com/handler.Php?Repeated=1">
    <Play>http://www.action.com/selection.mp3?1925924752</Play>
  </Gather>
  <Redirect Method="GET">http://www.action.com/handler.php?repeated=1</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.